# JavaFX change parent of a node while dragging

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, parent-child

I'm trying to realise a game where you can drag your figures from outside the board onto cards that are placed on the board.

The board is content of a scrollpane which is in a sibling relation to the pane that holds the figures.

The boardPane and stackPane (which are the two that need to be switched) are both instances of the class Pane.

What i need to do is switch the parent of the dragged figure from its parent pane to the new pane while i am moving it over the other pane.

I can not switch the parent on the MousePressed Event because the figure would then be placed where it is not visible.

```
f.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
                // if follower gets dragged from the stackPane onto the scrollPane, change its parent to boardPane
                if (stackPane.getChildren().contains(f) && sp.getBoundsInParent().contains(f.getBoundsInParent())) {
                    Bounds followerBoundsBoardPane = boardPane.sceneToLocal(f.getBoundsInParent());
                    stackPane.getChildren().remove(f);
                    f.setTranslateX(followerBoundsBoardPane.getMinX());
                    f.setTranslateY(followerBoundsBoardPane.getMinY());
                    boardPane.getChildren().add(f);
                }
                Point2D eventInParent = f.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
                double relX = eventInParent.getX() - deltaX;
                double relY = eventInParent.getY() - deltaY;
                f.setTranslateX(eventInParent.getX() - deltaX);
                f.setTranslateY(eventInParent.getY() - deltaY);

                event.consume();
            });
```

This is my code for dragging the figure (follower).

When i use this code, the figures parent is correctly changed, but i cant move it anymore after that.

When printing out the position in the dragevent, i can see, that the event stops firing after changing the parent, though the OnMouseReleased event does not fire. This one fires, when i release the mouse button.

Maybe this "log" helps understanding, what i mean:

```
In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 417,000000, 682,000000
relative:      398,000000, 661,000000

In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 418,000000, 680,000000
relative:      399,000000, 659,000000

In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 421,000000, 675,000000
relative:      402,000000, 654,000000

In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 421,000000, 673,000000
relative:      402,000000, 652,000000

In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 424,000000, 668,000000
relative:      405,000000, 647,000000

In OnMouseDragged Handler
eventInParent: 8799,250000, 9441,339844
relative:      8780,250000, 9420,339844
```

Can anyone tell me what i have to change or if what i want to achieve is possible?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: A couple of options come to mind: one is to move the object when the mouse is pressed to a common parent of the panes it starts in and might end in. You'd have to do some trickery with coordinate changes to get the right starting place. Then change coordinates when dragging, and when the mouse is released, move it to the target pane. Another option is to use the "platform-supported drag and drop gesture" mode (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html, "Dragging Gestures") instead; set the drag image to a snapshot of the node.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is you suggestions sounds good at first, but in need to rely on the MouseDragEntered/MouseDragExited/MouseDragReleased events that are set on my card nodes.
That seems to only be possible, if the dragged node (figure) is child of the same parent.

Comment: Not sure I really follow that. You should probably create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the same issue you are trying to solve, and post it in your question. (I understand it might be tricky with something that's moderately complex like this, but it's unlikely you'd get useful help if you post unrepresentative code snippets. Include everything we need to know from the outset.)

Comment: Oops. I tried to recreate the behavior for an example and because i got problems, i looked in my actual project and found out, that the part this thread is about, isn't actually needed.

So i solved my problem now. I thought i had to add the node to the same Pane to fire the needed events, but they also do, if the nodes are in different panes.

Thank you though for your help.

Comment: It always helps to create a MCVE. Many times it actually leads you to a solution: if it doesn't it makes it easier for others to find one when you post here. Glad you solved the issue.